# SQL Server : Date Comparison

Tags: sql-server

In this SQL Server query, I am trying to compare two date function. I have taken care of the fact that both have the same format (dd/mm/yy) and the code is working fine but my question is how can I compare `ApptStartDateTime` to `@AppDate`?

If I just use the `=` equal sign instead of `>=`, the code is not working. I just want to find it for that specific day and not after the `@AppDate`.

Thanks in advance.

```
WHERE A.ApptStartDateTime >=  CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @AppDate, 103), 103)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You verify equality with '='.

My guess is that your `A.ApptStartDateTime` is not exactly the same as your converted date. Make sure that you really have the same dates in the same format, i.e. the hours/minutes/seconds are not counted for.

Answer (score 0):

It was a very silly error turned out at the end. Although I converted ApptStartDateTime to dd/mm/yyyy format, I didnt use the same conversion while comparing the two values.

The result should be :

```
   WHERE CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),A.ApptStartDateTime,103),103) = CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@AppDate,103),103)
```